# Building kd-tree in cuda

Tags: data-structures, cuda, parallel-processing

For example I have array of (x,y) points and I want to organize them in kd-tree

Building kd-tree includes sorting and computing bounding boxes. These algorithms work fine on CUDA, but is there any way to build kd-tree utilizing as many threads as possible?

I think there should be some tricks:

Usually, kd-tree is implemented with recursion, but as far as I know, CUDA processors don't have hardware stack, so recursion should be avoided.

How can I build kd-tree in Cuda effectively?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the following papers:

- Stackless KD-Tree Traversal for High Performance GPU Ray Tracing
- Real-Time KD-Tree Construction on Graphics Hardware

They might help you along. Google them and you'll find them available online.